# Grails Scaffolding - define possible values for this property of a domain class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-constraints

I am new to Grails. I have a Person domain class as :

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String gender
    Date dateOfBirth
}
```

And wondering if I can define possible values for a property - say gender as {M, F, U} so  that these three values will be listed in combo box when using dynamic scaffolding for Person controller.

Here I just wanted to know if there is such feature in Grails framework? If such feature exists , then how can I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html, you should be able to use an inList constraint:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String gender
    Date dateOfBirth

    def constraints = {
        gender( inList: ["M", "F", "U"])
    }
}
```

This should scaffold to a select list for the gender field, depending on the version of Grails you're using.  2.0+ definitely does this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    enum Gender {
        M(1),
        F(2),
        U(3)
        private Gender(int val) { this.id = val }
        final int id
    }
    Gender gender = Gender.U
    Date dateOfBirth

    def constraints = {
        gender()
    }
}
```

This will store gender in the database as an integer (1,2,3) and default the gender to U.  The benefit here is you can rename what F, M, and U mean without handling a data migration.